# jQuery - How to select dropdown list item by text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How would I select my dropdown list item by text rather than value?

I want to select a dropdown item by text with jQuery.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

use [:contains()<sup>(link)</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$("select option:contains(text)").attr('selected', true);
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/TZmEw/)

Comment: If you need to do a variable:
var text = "Item 1";
$("select option:contains(" + text + ")").attr('selected', true);

Comment: This works fine unless you have similar items. For example, if you search for "item" and the options are "item 1", "item 2", etc. then you will get more than one result

Comment: with newer versions of jquery (1.6.1+?), use prop('selected',true) instead of attr('selected',true)

Comment: @PostureOfLearning : any solution for similar items?

Comment: OK I was able to do it and posted my answer.

Comment: For similar items you can choose the first item found using `$("select option:contains(text):first").attr('selected', true);`

Answer (score 10):

There is a [filter function on jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) that you can use to get elements with something more specific

```
$("select option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "text_to_select";
});
```

This is going to return all options with the "text_to_select" in the text.

Comment: THIS should be the accepted answer. Using "contains" could match several values, which could be dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

i think this will do the trick for you...

```
$("#selectId").find("option:contains('text')").each(function(){
  if( $(this).text() == 'Text that should be matched' ) {
    $(this).attr("selected","selected");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I use (it's not quite the same as the other suggestions here, and works with jQuery v1.8.3)

```
var userToSearchFor = 'mike';   //  Select any options containing this text

$("#ListOfUsers").find("option:contains('" + userToSearchFor +"')").each(function () {
   $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
});

<select id="ListOfUsers" ></select>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario with dropdowns for country, state and city. Country had "India" as well as "British Indian Ocean Territory". The issue with `:contains()` is that it attempts on both matches. I did something like:

```
$('#country option').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == 'India'){
        $(this).prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("selecter option:contains('" + data[i].ID+ "')").attr('selected', 'selected');
```